# Trying to create a toplist Laravel. But it's more about SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

...But if it's possible then I could Eloquent instead, but I do think with this problem i need to write a SQL-question.

I have a users table, and a points column. If I do want a top list then I just do order by points DESC (but with Eloquent and the user model).

To the question how do I do to found out which position any user has? Is it possible? Or should i make another table for toplist, please come with feedback and sorry for my poor english.

```
<?php

    $toplist = User::orderBy('points', 'DESC')->get();

    $me = Auth::user()->points;
    $position = 1;
    foreach($toplist as $user)
    {
        if ($user->id === $me)
        {
            break;
        }
        $position++;
    }

    dd($position);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. We'd be happy to help, but we'd like for you to show a bit more effort first. Could you post a sample of what you've already tried? What does your database look like? Have you tried going through the documentation? If you can answer those questions, I'm sure you'll get help in no time!

Comment: I thought this lines of code would get the position the current user have in the toplist, but no...
I would like something cleaner. Don't think that even works.

[code pastie](http://pastie.org/private/fdpyg0kfzxbdww0tkeor2a)

Comment: After your fetch the data you already have this field. Try `print_r $results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I do to found out which position any user has? Is it possible?

You can get your current rank by count user who have more points than you and then plus one.

```
$me   = Auth::user();
$rank = User::where('points', '>', $me->points)->count() + 1;
```